# Seria possivel eu me conectar ao um servidor em java usando Socket basico usando um client em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java

Eu estou estudando desenvolvimento de jogos e ultimamente considerei desenvolver um jogo próximo ou ate mesmo online.

Tem duas IDE em que eu posso desenvolver jogos, Unity3D e RPG Maker MV que utilizam da linguagem javascript.

Sou iniciante em javascript então desde já me desculpem pela pergunta, mas, eu gostaria de saber se eu consigo usar alguma biblioteca em javascript para me conectar a um servidor em que eu ando desenvolvendo em java?

Detalhe: no servidor eu utilizo o ServerSocket basico com bloqueio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, pois sockets trabalham com descritores de arquivo (textos), conceito padronizado no Unix BSD.

Em um socket você envia um texto e recebe um texto, mas pode ser transferidos outros tipos de dados, depende das suas API's.

Comment: Consigo comunicação mesmo usando websockets em js pra me conectar ao servidor em java?

Comment: Consegue sim, como eu disse na resposta você escreve um texto e lê um texto. Recomendo usar as APIs de comunicação padrão HTTP, que são implementações de sockets trabalhando com texto.